# jquery - in the table how can i move a colum in to where i want

Tags: jquery, dom

I do have a table, to manipulate, but i giving a sample here.. is my table contains the th and td, i suppose to find a column using the th's title, and i need to move that column in to where i want.

in my case i made a work, and trying to append to morning column after the evening, but i am getting wrong result any one correct me?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Morning</th>
            <th>Afternoon</th>
            <th>Evening</th>
        </tr>
<tbody>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>go to School</td>
            <td>go to Lunch</td>
            <td>go to Sleep</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
var morningIndex = $('tr th:contains(Morning)').index();
var Evening = $('tr th:contains(Evening)');


$.each($('tr'), function(n,v){
    morningCol = $(v).children().get(morningIndex);
    $(Evening).after(morningCol);
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFLDK/1/)

Comment: You need to be more specific than "getting wrong result" - **What** result are you getting, and why isn't it what you want?

Comment: yes i agree, in the browser it's appending after the last column badly, but in the fiddle i am getting some what different.

Comment: Again, don't say "some what different" - you need to provide **specifics** and tell us **exactly** what you're seeing, why it's wrong, etc. Something along the lines of (based on what I saw after making some changes to your fiddle so it ran for me): "All of the cells that need to be moved are being added to the end of the first row. This isn't correct because what I actually want is for them to be placed at the end of the row they're currently in."

Comment: in the fiddle i am not getting the result at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working for me:

```
var morningIndex = $('tr th:contains(Morning)').index();
var Evening =  $('tr th:contains(Evening)').index();

        $.each($("table tr"), function() { 
            $(this).children(":eq("+Evening+")").after($(this).children(":eq("+morningIndex+")"));
        });
```

Thanks all.